# How to customize MVC url path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a clean URL path to an MVC controller and I need a little assistance.

Example desired path: `http://www.linkedin.com/in/alumcloud`. This path is from LinkedIn and notice how it has the `/in/alumcloud`.

I would like for mine to read: `http://www.alumcloud.com/alumcloud/somecompanyname`

**How would I do this with an MVC controller?**

Below is the only code in my MVC controller, becuase this controller is only needed to respond to `GET HTTP` methods.

```
public class AlumCloudController : AlumCloudMvcControllerBase
{
    // GET: /AlumCloud/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(string companyName)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**--Here is my RouteConfig**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**-----------------------------------2nd Attempt------------------------------------**

**--Route Code 2**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Public",
                url: "ac/{companyName}",
                defaults: new { controller = "AlumCloudController", action = "UserProfile" }
            );
 }
```

**--Controller Code 2**

```
public class AlumCloudController : AlumCloudMvcControllerBase
{
    // GET: /AlumCloud/Details/5
    public ActionResult UserProfile(string companyName)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**--The URL**

```
'/ac/' + options.person.CompanyName
```

**--Snap shot of 404 error**

[image: 404 mvc error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this route **above** your default:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Profile",
    url: "alumcloud/{companyName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "AlumCloudController", action = "Details" }
);
```

Comment: Perfect. Though, you might want to change value of name in  `name: "Default"` to something else. It could hurt rest of the app.

Comment: Thanks for the catch @Abhinav - missed that one.

Comment: I'm missing something somewhere. I've updated the original post with my issues. I cannot seem to get the url to read mydomain/ac/acompanyname. It keeps changing it back to mydomain/acompanyname

Comment: 2 things: 1) your new route needs to go **above** the default.  2) In your screenshot, you're missing the `/ac/` part of the URL.

Comment: Turns out that my naming convention was incorrect. I've got a folder named AlumCloud and that was what MVC routing was pointing to. So I changed the name of the controller and it works. Thank you for showing me the correct way to add the routing.